# EntityFramework query error: <entityS>

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my MVC project I use EntityFramework. The entity's name is RatingSource. In the DB table is named RatingSource. I use "RatingSource" everywhere in the project, not "RatingSources" ("s" in the end). But when I start the project I catch an error "There is no object dbo.RatingSources", and the query which EF creates is "SELECT bla-bla-bla FROM dbo.RatingSources". Where is a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to convention of Entity framework. You can say to EF what is name of table for this entity by attribute or fluent interface. You can use attribute `[Table("RatingSource")]` on class `RatingSource` to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank u. What attribute and where I should write it?